# Convert SpenObjectBase to String for EditText

Tags: android, sdk, android-edittext, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am working on Samsung Mobile SDK and using it's TextRecognition feature for recognition of text written on SpenSurfaceView. I have done this using example provided by Samsung. After conversion I receive data as object SpenObjectBase class.
**Now my question is can we convert this SpenObjectBase object as String so that I can show the converted text in EditText ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try casting it to `SpenObjectText` and then extracting `CharSequence` with `getText()` method:

```
SpenObjectBase base = //.. your object containing text data
if (base instanceof SpenObjectText) {
    SpenObjectText text = (SpenObjectText) base;
    mEditText.setText(text.getText());
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you provide sample code or demo to convert "text written on SpenSurfaceView" to string.                                                                  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pradeep you can download sample from http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile/start

Comment: @JaiSoni: I have already downloaded PenSDK_v3.0.19(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053715/how-to-us-galaxy-notes-handwriting-recogntion) and run the text recognition code (example5_6) but not able to making work it properly.