# How to us Galaxy Note's handwriting recogntion

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I have a simple prototype that receives spen input.  I would like to recognize the text inputed by the user.  Does the Galaxy Note family (Note 8, Note 2 and 3) provide an intent where you input the strokes and get out text recognized output ?

Comment: Samsung has a Mobile SDK for integrating S-Pen input.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I could not find any handwriting recognition in it.  It just has the signature recognizer.  MyScript licenses handwriting recognition, but we only need it on Note devices that already have HWR license in them.  So I ask if there is a way to connect to it.

Comment: "I could not find any handwriting recognition in it" -- http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk#pen

Comment: Thanks, yes I see it.  I downloaded the SPen SDK and thought it was not HR was not provided by Samsung, but the text recognition API is in the Samsung Mobile SDK.

Comment: could you please share how to use the api code?

Comment: @jeremyvillalobos - did you manage to perform handwriting to text? could you please guide how to go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Samsung Mobile SDK

http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk

The sample project at:

Samsung_Mobile_SDK_1.5/Samples/Pen/src/com/samsung/android/sdk/pen/pg/example5_6

shows how to use text recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Do not freeze or disable HandwritingService if you use galaxy note series. Because this service essentially convert your handwriten text into preferred type such as task, phone number or emal. If you disable or delete this service, s note stops working when you try to select and convert handwritten text.

Comment: I can't see any relation between your answer and OP's question. Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

in case someone is still looking for text recognition, there's the ML Kit from google that does the same thing:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition